# Acumatica - Opportunities Create Quote button - Contract-Based REST API

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I have created an endpoint to use the Create Quote action on the Opportunities page. When I sent the POST to the Action I get a 202 response but the Quote is never made. I believe it is because I am only "clicking" the Create New Quote and not the Create button(or Create and Review) on the Dialog box?

Is this a limitation on the REST API? because in the Wiki they do take about the Pop-up Panels with the SOAP connection:
https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=0ff94cd6-a46e-4cf7-8b97-51b79a6b3257

Answer (score 0):

The 202 response only means that the action was accepted and is in progress.

In order to see the actual result you will need to perform a GET on the URL in the Location header of the response

You can find more information about this here :

https://help-2020r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=91bf9106-062a-47a8-be1f-b48517a54324

Check the Response and Status Code sections